# Убрать панельку ASP MVC со страниц

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Каким образом можно убрать эту панель?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: найти ее в `Site.master` и удалить

Comment: @Igor где это находится?

Comment: `Site.master` - имя файла в `Views\Shared`

Comment: @Igor у меня такого файла в папке Shared нет, только _Layout, _ValidationScriptPartial, Error

Comment: значит это - `Layout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно убрать/закомментировать следующие строки в файле _Layout:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">ASPMVC</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</nav>

<footer>
        <p>&copy; 2018 - ASPMVC</p>
    </footer>
```